# JAXB bind supertype properties

Tags: java, jaxb

There are:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="A", propOrder={"k", "l"})
public class A {

    @XmlElement(name="kkk")
    protected K k;

    @XmlElement(name="lll")
    protected L l;
}
```

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="B")
public class B extends A {
}
```

In xsd it looks like:

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="A">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="kkk" type="K" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="lll" type="L" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="B">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="A"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

But when I try to parse element of type `B` like:

```xml
...
  <b>
    <kkk>...</kkk>
    <lll>...</lll>
  </b>
...
```

I get error like:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 35; cvc-
complex-type.2.1: Element 'b' must have no character or element information item
 [children], because the type's content type is empty.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry. There was my fault: in my xsd was `xsd:restriction` instead of `xsd:extension`.

Comment: So you've solved it? Feel free to post your own answer. This will provide other users who will run into the similar problem guidance on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The given example is totally right. The problem was that [`xsd:restriction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256061(v=vs.110).aspx) tag was used instead of [`xsd:extension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256161(v=vs.110).aspx). Their difference is that `restriction` disallows some elements, attributes, or values that the base type permits, and `extension` allows additional attributes and elements to appear.[*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)#Types)

So, in my case I had disallowed any `A` elements within `B` type, until I found that I use a wrong tag.